# How to migrate federation identity from Auth0 to Azure AD B2C?

Tags: amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c, auth0

Federation identity are like sign up with Google, or sign up with Facebook. I want to migrate from Auth0 to Azure, but the problem is I can't find any proper documentation that explains what happen to those users who signed up using their Google or Facebook account.

There are good documentation for username and password users, but there is not anything special for federation identity users.

Does anyone know how to migrate them?

I have the same question for Amazon Cognito and other alternative services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not always straightforward, because some IdPs issue a different UUID per Application Registration. If you can re-use the exact same Application Registration at Facebook, for example, with AAD B2C, then this can be fairly easy.

There is an example here:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account

All you need to do is pre-create the Local accounts in AAD B2C, and provide the expected UUID from the federated IdPs token to the Local account user object in AAD B2C. AAD B2C can then link the account when the user comes in with that Facebook account.

Comment: You dont migrate the UUID of the Auth0 user. You migrate the UUID from the federated IdP. Auth0 must store the Facebook users UUID in its user store somewhere, thats how it would match the Facebook user to the Auth0 user account. If Auth0 doesnt store anything, then you need to get the UUIDs from the federated IdP's yourself (faecbook, google etc).

Comment: Thank you! what is the solution in case that we don't have UUID?

Comment: Match on something that you think is “unique” enough. I don’t recommend it though.